# Не запускается код на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нейрнонная сеть

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                        [1,1,1],
                        [1,0,1],
                        [0,1,1]])

training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random((3,1)) - 1

print("Случайные инициализирующие веса:")
print(synaptic_weights)

for 1 in range(20000):
input_layer = training_inputs
outputs = sigmoid( np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights) )

err = training_outputs - outputs
adjustments = np.dot( input_Layer.T, err * (outputs * (1 - outputs)) )

synaptic_weights += adjustments

print(" Веса после обучения ")    
print(synaptic_weights) 

Print( "Результат после обучения:" )
Print(outputs)
```

Comment: В 4 строке Вы забыли отступ. Это ошибка форматирования на SO, или у Вас и в исходнике так?

Comment: Также, было бы неплохо привести в вопросе ваш Traceback.

Comment: У меня ошибка в 22 строке

Comment: outputs = sigmoid( np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights) )

Comment: У Вас написано `for 1`, может Вы имели в виду `for i`?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код невалиден.

Ошибок много:

1. Отступы после `def` и `for`
2. Вызов объекта модуля `np.random` (исправил на `np.random.random`)
3. Неправильно указана переменная для итерирования в цикле `for` (исправил на `i`)
4. Неинициализированная переменная `input_Layer` (исправил на `input_layer`)
5. Неинициализированная функция Print (исправил на `print`)

***Код:***

```py
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(1)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                        [1,1,1],
                        [1,0,1],
                        [0,1,1]])

training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

print("Случайные инициализирующие веса:")
print(synaptic_weights)

for i in range(20000):
    input_layer = training_inputs
    outputs = sigmoid( np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights) )

    err = training_outputs - outputs
    adjustments = np.dot( input_layer.T, err * (outputs * (1 - outputs)) )

    synaptic_weights += adjustments

print(" Веса после обучения ")    
print(synaptic_weights) 

print( "Результат после обучения:" )
print(outputs)
```

***P. S.:***
Посмотрели видео в интернете и пошли писать нейронку? Не беда, SO ведь благотворительная фриланс-биржа, всё пофиксят, всё подправят... Простите, крик души...

Также, следуйте, пожалуйста, `PEP-8`